# String replace numeric value exact match

Tags: php, wordpress, string, str-replace

I have string "http://www.test.com/abcd.html?page_num=1". I want to replace "?page_num=1" with blank string. Because I want only "http://www.test.com/abcd.html" URL.

I have tried with below code:

```
str_replace('?page_num=1','',$str);
```

but if their is 13 after page_num then i got http://www.test.com/abcd.html3 because of replacement.

Comment: What if you have `http://www.test.com/abcd.html?page_num=1&other=121`?

Comment: no i have not passed any other parameter. Just i have html and their is href with page_num=1 which i want to remove but only 1 not other page_num remove

Comment: Why not you change in `href` directly ?

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47975750/8927508) ?

Comment: yes i have checked but i have lots of pagination link with html and i want to replace only first page link "1" with actual link.

Comment: are you getting my point?

Comment: No I am not getting your point. If you still not solved your problem, as 28 viewed your question and you already have 4 answer then definitely your question is unclear to us.

Comment: Let me explain you i am using wordpress paginate_links function and it returns pagination html. from that pagination html when we found page 1 link it remove parameter and redirect actual link without parameters.That's why i am replace the string but somehow it not works when page 10 or 11 etc found beacuse i replace page_num=1 with blank html. Let me know if you are still not getting my point.

Comment: is any answer worked for you ?

Comment: thank you from the all answer i have solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved issue

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<!\.)\b\?page_num=1\b(?!\.)/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to match numbers, something like following:

```
$string = "http://www.test.com/abcd.html?page_num=12";
$res = preg_replace("/\?page_num=\d+/", "", $string);
echo $res;
```

Comment: She is saying `I want only "http://www.test.com/abcd.html"` your answer will fail if url is something `abcd.html?page_num=1&other=121`  ?

Comment: And regex always needed a value like `page_num=12` if also fails if it is `page_num=`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by just `explode`

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.test.com/abcd.html?page_num=1';
echo explode('?',$url)[0];
?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/925182

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use Regular Expression instead of plain str_replace(). str_replace() will only making exact replacement, while by RegExp we can do pattern replacement.

To accomplish your goal, I suggest to use this instead:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\?page_num=\d+$#i', '', $str);
```

If you'd like to learn more about RegExp, try [this resource](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look, I have done some modification in your code and achieve the result

First I have found the position of '?' and break the string from into a substring

```
<?php

   $str = "http://www.test.com/abcd.html?page_num=12";   
   $replaceString = substr($str, strpos($str, "?") );    
   $string = str_replace(replaceString, '', $str);
   echo $string;

?>
```

> substr(): Function returns a part of a string
>
> strpos(): Finds the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by subString

```
$url= "http://www.test.com/abcd.html?page_num=1";
$newurl = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "?"));
```